# Как выбрать несколько элементов ListView длинным нажатием (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

Нужно получить список элементов выделенных пользователем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, из коробки такое не возможно.

Общая концепция решения хорошо реализована вот тут:
https://github.com/acaliaro/ListViewWithMultipleItemsSelection
Ключевые моменты следющие:

**TestListViewMultiSelectItemsPage.xaml**:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="ItemTapped">
            <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"/>
            </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" TextColor = "Fuchsia" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand"/>
                        <BoxView Color="Fuchsia" IsVisible="{Binding Selected}" HorizontalOptions = "End"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**TestListViewMultiSelectItemsViewModel.cs**

```
ItemTappedCommand = new Command((object model) => {

            if (model != null && model is ItemTappedEventArgs) {
                if (!((Model)((ItemTappedEventArgs)model).Item).Selected)
                    SelectedItemsCounter++;
                else
                    SelectedItemsCounter--;

                ((Model)((ItemTappedEventArgs)model).Item).Selected = !((Model)((ItemTappedEventArgs)model).Item).Selected;
            }
        });
```

В данном случае при нажатии на ViewCell обрабатывается событие вызовом команды: **ItemTappedCommand**
Вам необходимо проделать небольшую работу по кастомизации контрола, либо поиска готовой библиотеки поддерживающей long press gesture.
Подробные варианты обсуждены вот здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569515/how-to-make-long-press-gesture-in-xamarin-forms